# Delay DIV appearances

Tags: jquery, loading

I am trying to delay occurrences of `#chamrs` and `#TopPlayedInVenueList1` DIVS because when `#charms` is loaded it brings the `#TopPlayedInVenueList1` which contains all the data and makes the overall transition very laggy while it loads the data. So I am trying to load `#charms` on it's on, then Ajax loading.gif while the data is loaded in the background.

The issue here with the code is that it still loads `#charms` and `#TopPlayedInVenueList1`  together and the Ajax loader doesn't hide once the data is displayed.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#charms").show(0).delay(0);
    $("#loading").show(1000).delay(1000);

    do_something();

    function do_something() {
        $("#loading").show();
        $.post("@Url.Action("TopPlayedInVenueList1")", function (data) {
        $("#TopPlayedInVenueContainer1").html();
        $("#loading").hide();
    });
};
```

})

Any help would be great help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using $("#TopPlayedInVenueContainer1").html("");? Put the two quotes inside the html()-function to delete the content. Otherwise, the function only returns the content, but doesn't change it.

Comment: Your ajax function is faster than you think, so the fadeIn happens after the hide in the ajax callback, and it all gets messed up. And fadeIn does nothing when the element is already visible.

Comment: @maja thanks.. I just tried it and it doesn't show the datatable like you said it deletes the content.

Comment: @adeneo thanks.. I have updated my code by removing the fadeIns. It still doesn't work and `#charms` and `#TopPlayedInVenueList1` still loads together.

Comment: Looks like you should have syntax error in console, isn't it?! I mean,  i'm not sure about your syntax here: `"@Url.Action("TopPlayedInVenueList1")"`

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? we can use animate/effect + callback functions so that things only happen when other things are finished.

Comment: @A.Wolff - I think the quotes are OK, the `@Url` directive is serverside and is replaced with a string by ASP.NET.

Comment: @adeneo Ya, i was really not sure about it, thx for the input!

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks - Nah I don't have any syntax error in my console.

Comment: @JFit thanks :) - here's the http://jsfiddle.net/xyPu8/1/ link `#chamrs` and `#TopPlayedInVenueList1` needs loading differently. They both messing it up together!

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/xyPu8/2/ maybe your `@Url.Action('TopPlayedInVenueList1')` is returning wrong data?

Comment: @JFit thanks a lot :) - the `@Url.Action('TopPlayedInVenueList1')` is fine and is giving out the right data from a C# method. The script is giving out the following error "Too many characters in character literal" for this particular line.. ` $.post("@Url.Action('TopPlayedInVenueList1')", function () {` and thanks again :)

Comment: whups, my bad.. had changed it in the fiddle cos i was just spoofing response.. should be  $.post('@Url.Action("TopPlayedInVenueList1")'

Comment: @JFit aahhh damn I didn't figure that out and it's cool and thanks :) - I tried the full code now, and sorry but it has two issues.. 1. `#chamrs` and `#TopPlayedInVenueList1 ` still loads together and 2. the loading doesn't hide.